# Record audio from iPhone browser

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc

Can someone please help how can I record audio from the browser of iPhone(iOS) and save it through an API on server. I read that WebRTC is now supported on iOS but it's not working. I tried this link from safari of iPhone - 
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/ but it's not able to play. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: show me your code. are you tried with AVAudioRecorder?